# Rails- Ruby Instance Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, variables, omniauth

So I am using omniauth-facebook to create a log in using Facebook.

Here is my `sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to "/sessions/menu"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def new
  end

  def menu
      puts user.name
  end

end
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to access the user variable in the menu action. How would you guys recommend I do this?

**Update**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to "/sessions/menu"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def new
  end

  def menu
      puts @user
  end

end
```

Even when I update it like so, it doesn't work

Comment: make it _ivar_ as `@user`...

Comment: Only one action in the controller ever fires at a time, after the router creates an instance of that controller for a given route. As a result `@user` or any other variable, whether an instance variable or a local one, wouldn't be defined within your menu action unless you assign it a value.

Comment: @JakeShorty Yes that's the reason..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately I don't know how to access the user variable in the menu
>   action. How would you guys recommend I do this?

Every time a request is made in your app for actions in `SessionsController`, a new instance of the `SessionsController` is created. So, instance variable set during `create` action would not be available when request for `menu` action is called as now you have a new instance of `SessionsController` which is why `@user` set in `create` action would not be available in `menu`. Also, if you use `user` (*local variable*) in this case, then its always local to the method/action in which its defined. So even that would not be available in `menu`.

By using `facebook-omniauth` gem you would receive Auth Hash in `env["omniauth.auth"]` which in turn you would use to create(new user) or initialize(in case of existing user) a user hopefully in `from_omniauth` method. 
**NOTE:** `env` is request specific so `env["omniauth.auth"]` value will be present in `create` action but not in `menu`.

To resolve this, i.e., to access the created or initialized facebook `user` in `menu` action, you should make use of the `user_id` that you stored in `session` as below:

```
def menu
  if session[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Also, if you would like to access the user in other actions as well then I would recommend to reuse the code by using `before_action` callback:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  ## Pass specific actions to "only" option
  before_action :set_user, only: [:menu, :action1, :action2]

  #...

  def menu
      puts @user.name
  end

  private

  def set_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

where you can add specific actions via `:only` option

Comment: Why `:only` option is needed ?

Comment: True. As OP didn't mention such stuffs, that's why I didn't care of it. But it seems you used thie Gem in your work a lot, that's why on the first chance you picked up. Good Job. Opportunity gives human beings a platform to become perfect... +1

Comment: Hum,... This Q was for me a "Good Morning" Q.. So missed it. :D you know my habit..  :D